# How to generate an APK with all assets from asset packs included?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-asset-delivery, android-assetpacks

I have android application with asset packs downloading at install time. Now I need an APK(galaxy build) with all the assets from asset packs included in it.

I have tried including this in app's build.gradle file

```
if (project.hasProperty("includeAssets")) { assetPacks = [":play_asset_test"] }
```

and used `./gradlew assembleGalaxyArm64Release -PincludeAssets` to generate apk. But this didn't work.

How to generate an APK with all assets from asset packs included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used used gradle properties and added it in the command and based on the property, include the asset pack location.

Gradle command:

```
./gradlew --project-prop includeAssetPackFiles assemblePlayArm64Release
```

In build.gradle set asset folders paths

```
if (project.hasProperty("includeAssetPackFiles")) {
     assets.srcDirs = ['../play_asset_test/src/main/assets', 'assets', '../play_asset_test_ff/src/main/assets']
} else {
     assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
}
```

This worked for me. Please share if there are any other approaches.